# JPA tools tab is not available in Spring Tool Suite 3 when need to create entities from tables?

Tags: spring-mvc, jpa, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

when need to create entities from tables in Spring Tool Suite 3, Java Persistence API tool is not enable......is there any change need for settings?

Comment: can you show what you mean by `Java Persistence API tool is not enable`